# A simple thread safe LRU cache using unordered map and lists in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, cache

> I am learning concurrent programming and am writing a thread safe LRU cache for practice. Below is my first attempt. Kindly comment and let me know where I can improve.

PS: There have already been a few questions asked on this topic but a more toned down version will help me understand the underlying concept of concurrency.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "thread"
#include "mutex"

class LRUCache
{

    std::mutex mu;

private:
    int cacheSize;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, std::list<int>::iterator>> cache;
    std::list<int> lru;
    void update(std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, std::list<int>::iterator>>::iterator &it);

public:
    void setSize(int size);
    int get(int key);
    void set(int key, int value);
};

void LRUCache::setSize(int size)
{
    std::lock_guard <std::mutex> locker(mu);
    cacheSize = size;
}

int LRUCache::get(int key)
{
    std::lock_guard <std::mutex> locker(mu);
    auto item = cache.find(key);

    if (item == cache.end())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    update(item);

    return item->second.first;
}

void LRUCache::set(int key, int value)
{
    std::lock_guard <std::mutex> locker(mu);

    auto item = cache.find(key);

    if (item != cache.end())
    {
        update(item);
        cache[key] = { value, lru.begin() };
        return;
    }

    if (cache.size() == cacheSize)
    {
        cache.erase(lru.back());
        lru.pop_back();
    }

    lru.push_front(key);
    cache.insert({ key,{ value, lru.begin() } });
}

void LRUCache::update(std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, std::list<int>::iterator>>::iterator &it)
{
    lru.erase(it->second.second);
    lru.push_front(it->first);
    it->second.second = lru.begin();
}

void function2(LRUCache *lruCache)
{
    lruCache->set(5, 5);
    lruCache->set(6, 6);
    lruCache->set(1, 1);

    std::cout << "F2::Successful Execution: " << lruCache->get(4) << std::endl;

    lruCache->set(8, 8);

    std::cout << "F2::Successful Execution: " << lruCache->get(1) << std::endl;
}

void function1(LRUCache *lruCache)
{
    lruCache->set(1, 1);
    lruCache->set(2, 2);
    lruCache->set(3, 3);

    std::cout << "F1::Successful Execution: " << lruCache->get(3) << std::endl;

    lruCache->set(4, 4);

    std::cout << "F1::Successful Execution: " << lruCache->get(2) << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    LRUCache *lruCache = new LRUCache();
    lruCache->setSize(2);

    std::thread t1(function1, lruCache);
    t1.join();

    std::thread t2(function2, lruCache);
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What part, exactly, is "toned down"? Do you mean that you want the *answers* to be toned down in terms of their complexity? If so, you might consider indicating that by adding the [beginner] tag. Or maybe you just mean that your code/implementation is simpler than the other questions? (Also, please don't use blockquotes to quote yourself!)

Comment: The latter, simpler code implementations